# Count records of statuses(approved, pending, rejected) and return values into their own individual variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to count documents in mongoDB (**using mongoose**) where records have a status of pending and approved as well as rejected. So, I am basically trying to get a result where I can show a count of each and display it in my view

And I want to hold these values in variables that I can use in different places ie:

```
const pending = .....
const approved = ....
const rejected = .....
```

I have tried to use the aggregate function and run a loop which gets me all the data I need but I don't know how to actually get the data into the three variables like above.

```
   Product.aggregate([
        { $group: { _id: { status: "$status" }, totalStatus: { $sum: 1 } } }

    ])
```

The above code gives me back this (I have no rejected values yet)

```
[
    {
        _id: {
            status: 'pending'
        },
        totalStatus: 15
    },
    {
        _id: {
            status: 'approved'
        },
        totalStatus: 27
    }
  ]
```

I then ran a loop and used destructuring:

```
.then(status => {
    for (const current of status) {
        const [status, total] = [current._id.status, current.totalStatus];
        console.log(status + ': ' + total);
    }
    next();
})
```

That gives me:

```
pending: 15
approved: 27
```

But it still isn't what I actually want. I need to get those values into their own variables. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the status and the document count with your aggregation. Please try this to get those values into their corresponding variables:

```
let pending, approved, rejected;

switch (status.toLowerCase()) {
 case 'pending': pending = total;
        break;
 case 'approved' : approved = total;
        break;
 case 'rejected': rejected = total;
        break;
}
```

Include the *switch* inside your loop.

Comment: that seems to work! Is it the right to do it like this or should the database be doing the work and giving me the results in the way I need them?

Comment: It's good if we can achieve it using mongoose itself. But I'm not sure whether it is possible or not!

Comment: okay. I will wait to see if I get any more answers here to see if it can be done using Mongoose.